# Display gaps in a Sencha Touch Cartesian Chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to display gaps in a chart serie. I'm using Sencha Touch 2.4.1. I already tried to set the data to "no data" which results in a solid line between the surrounding data records ([Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3df)). Setting the data to null results in a zero value in the chart.

Is there a way to display a gap in the serie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lb9

It uses renderer to define transparent color for some parts of the chart. More information you can find here: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Line-cfg-renderer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this is if I have empty or null values in my store which will be the case in my app the chart looks like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lbc   

Do you have any further suggestions for me?

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement. Can you provide more details?

Comment: In the store I'm using for the chart some of the values used for the line serie are null or an empty string for these values I need to display gaps in the chart. Let me know if I can clearify this any further.

Comment: What I would like to achive is something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hga  But unfortunatly this doesn't work with sencha touch charts

Comment: I don't there is a way to do this using null value. It's better to use another field. I updated the fiddle, try it: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lb9